# Re-position of popup in jquery or css

Tags: jquery, css

I'm displaying a pop up box by clicking a certain button. Like when you hover over the menu area you get a border while clicking the same area buttons are being displayed, same thing happens with the tab area of `why with us?` But while doing this box is being displayed in an awkward position. It scrolls the main content too. I want it to be fixed and display where its being clicked. Following is [the link to my project](http://www.noeticitservices.com/nitsdemo/NitsEditor/edit/editor.php)

I'm taking position with the mouse move function following is the code:

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove(function (f) {
    mouseX = f.pageX;
    mouseY = f.pageY;
});
```

And putting adding css to popups.

```
$('#nitstabeditor').fadeIn(400).css({
     'top': mouseY
   , 'left': mouseX
})
```

Please help me guys.

CSS being used:

```
 #nitstabeditor {
    z-index: 9999;
 }
 #nitstabeditor {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   min-width: 250px;
 }
```

Comment: can you make fiddle ?

Comment: Project link is already there in the question

Comment: but where is popup link ?

Comment: Clicking on what certain button?

Comment: you mean you don't want to scroll to be top when user click on edit or add button right ?

Comment: Yes exactly I don't want to scroll it. I want it to be fixed

Comment: use preventDefault() on btn click

Comment: Got it thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preventDefault()` to solve this issue for example

```
$("#nitstabbutton .btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
   //your code here
});
```